# Issue with Opera browser: center a table and text-align on left

Tags: html, css, opera

On opera browser, I get an issue about a table that I would like to center and in which the text should be aligned on left.

I have the CSS:

```
div.center table{
text-align: left;
margin: 0 auto;
}

td.code_box{
font-family: monospace;
background-color: #333333;
border: 1px ridge;
height: 50px;
color: #CCCCCC;
padding: 5px;
}
```

and the HTML code snippet:

```
<div class="center">
<table><tr><td class="code_box">
<font color="#ffff00"># Inputs</font><br>
NET&nbsp;<font color="#c00000">&quot;l&quot;</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;LOC =&nbsp;<font color="#c00000">&quot;T9&quot;</font>&nbsp;;<br>
NET&nbsp;<font color="#c00000">&quot;b&quot;</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;LOC =&nbsp;<font color="#c00000">&quot;T10&quot;</font>&nbsp;;<br>
NET&nbsp;<font color="#c00000">&quot;h&quot;</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;LOC =&nbsp;<font color="#c00000">&quot;V9&quot;</font>&nbsp;;<br>
NET&nbsp;<font color="#c00000">&quot;rst&quot;</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;LOC =&nbsp;<font color="#c00000">&quot;M8&quot;</font>&nbsp;;<br>
<br>
<font color="#ffff00"># Outputs</font><br>
NET&nbsp;<font color="#c00000">&quot;s0&quot;</font>&nbsp;LOC =&nbsp;<font color="#c00000">&quot;U16&quot;</font>&nbsp;;<br>
NET&nbsp;<font color="#c00000">&quot;s1&quot;</font>&nbsp;LOC =&nbsp;<font color="#c00000">&quot;V16&quot;</font>&nbsp;;<br>
NET&nbsp;<font color="#c00000">&quot;s2&quot;</font>&nbsp;LOC =&nbsp;<font color="#c00000">&quot;U15&quot;</font>&nbsp;;<br>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work on Opera browser, the table is aligned on the left and is not centered. What might be wrong?

### Update 1

I have the following text file:

```
# Inputs
NET "l"  LOC = "T9" ;
NET "b"  LOC = "T10" ;
NET "h"  LOC = "V9" ;
NET "rst"  LOC = "M8" ;

# Outputs
NET "s0" LOC = "U16" ;
NET "s1" LOC = "V16" ;
NET "s2" LOC = "U15" ;
```

I want to convert this small text file into HTML code. For this, I use under `vim` the command "`:TOhtml`" which generates this code snippet:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>~/robot.ucf.html</title>
<meta name="Generator" content="Vim/7.3">
<meta name="plugin-version" content="vim7.3_v6">
<meta name="syntax" content="conf">
<meta name="settings" content="no_pre">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff" text="#000000">
<font face="monospace">
<font color="#0000c0"># Inputs</font><br>
NET&nbsp;<font color="#c00000">&quot;l&quot;</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;LOC =&nbsp;<font color="#c00000">&quot;T9&quot;</font>&nbsp;;<br>
NET&nbsp;<font color="#c00000">&quot;b&quot;</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;LOC =&nbsp;<font color="#c00000">&quot;T10&quot;</font>&nbsp;;<br>
NET&nbsp;<font color="#c00000">&quot;h&quot;</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;LOC =&nbsp;<font color="#c00000">&quot;V9&quot;</font>&nbsp;;<br>
NET&nbsp;<font color="#c00000">&quot;rst&quot;</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;LOC =&nbsp;<font color="#c00000">&quot;M8&quot;</font>&nbsp;;<br>
<br>
<font color="#0000c0"># Outputs</font><br>
NET&nbsp;<font color="#c00000">&quot;s0&quot;</font>&nbsp;LOC =&nbsp;<font color="#c00000">&quot;U16&quot;</font>&nbsp;;<br>
NET&nbsp;<font color="#c00000">&quot;s1&quot;</font>&nbsp;LOC =&nbsp;<font color="#c00000">&quot;V16&quot;</font>&nbsp;;<br>
NET&nbsp;<font color="#c00000">&quot;s2&quot;</font>&nbsp;LOC =&nbsp;<font color="#c00000">&quot;U15&quot;</font>&nbsp;;<br>
</font>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I would like to take only the `HTML text content` content above and insert it into a table, i.e this part:

```
<font color="#0000c0"># Inputs</font><br>
NET&nbsp;<font color="#c00000">&quot;l&quot;</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;LOC =&nbsp;<font color="#c00000">&quot;T9&quot;</font>&nbsp;;<br>
NET&nbsp;<font color="#c00000">&quot;b&quot;</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;LOC =&nbsp;<font color="#c00000">&quot;T10&quot;</font>&nbsp;;<br>
NET&nbsp;<font color="#c00000">&quot;h&quot;</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;LOC =&nbsp;<font color="#c00000">&quot;V9&quot;</font>&nbsp;;<br>
NET&nbsp;<font color="#c00000">&quot;rst&quot;</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;LOC =&nbsp;<font color="#c00000">&quot;M8&quot;</font>&nbsp;;<br>
<br>
<font color="#0000c0"># Outputs</font><br>
NET&nbsp;<font color="#c00000">&quot;s0&quot;</font>&nbsp;LOC =&nbsp;<font color="#c00000">&quot;U16&quot;</font>&nbsp;;<br>
NET&nbsp;<font color="#c00000">&quot;s1&quot;</font>&nbsp;LOC =&nbsp;<font color="#c00000">&quot;V16&quot;</font>&nbsp;;<br>
NET&nbsp;<font color="#c00000">&quot;s2&quot;</font>&nbsp;LOC =&nbsp;<font color="#c00000">&quot;U15&quot;</font>&nbsp;;<br>
</font>
```

by doing:

```
<div class="center">
<table><tr><td class="code_box">
...
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

I have tried by adding `text-align: left;` to `code_box` CSS:

```
td.code_box{
font-family: monospace;
text-align: left;
background-color: #333333;
border: 1px ridge;
height: 50px;
color: #CCCCCC;
padding: 5px;
}
```

but this doesn't seem to work.

Is there a better solution to center this table (with a `div` parent ?) and in the same time, left align the content of `<td class="code_box">`.

### Update 2

You can see my issue on [this page](http://beulu.com/test_issue).

As you can notice, the `code box` has text-aligned on left but **the div is not centered horizontally**.

I have used this `CSS rule` for the div:

```
div.center-left table{ text-align: left; margin: 0 auto; }
```

and set for HTML:

```
<div class="center-left">
<table><tr><td class="code_box">
<font color="#ffff00"># Inputs</font><br>
NET&nbsp;<font color="#c00000">&quot;l&quot;</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;LOC =&nbsp;<font color="#c00000">&quot;T9&quot;</font>&nbsp;;<br>
NET&nbsp;<font color="#c00000">&quot;b&quot;</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;LOC =&nbsp;<font color="#c00000">&quot;T10&quot;</font>&nbsp;;<br>
NET&nbsp;<font color="#c00000">&quot;h&quot;</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;LOC =&nbsp;<font color="#c00000">&quot;V9&quot;</font>&nbsp;;<br>
NET&nbsp;<font color="#c00000">&quot;rst&quot;</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;LOC =&nbsp;<font color="#c00000">&quot;M8&quot;</font>&nbsp;;<br>
<br>
<font color="#ffff00"># Outputs</font><br>
NET&nbsp;<font color="#c00000">&quot;s0&quot;</font>&nbsp;LOC =&nbsp;<font color="#c00000">&quot;U16&quot;</font>&nbsp;;<br>
NET&nbsp;<font color="#c00000">&quot;s1&quot;</font>&nbsp;LOC =&nbsp;<font color="#c00000">&quot;V16&quot;</font>&nbsp;;<br>
NET&nbsp;<font color="#c00000">&quot;s2&quot;</font>&nbsp;LOC =&nbsp;<font color="#c00000">&quot;U15&quot;</font>&nbsp;;<br>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Now, I realise this issue also appears on Firefox, not only on Opera. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I viewed your code in the latest version of Opera and the table is centered. What version are you using? Perhaps there is something else in your code interfering.

Comment: I am using Opera 41.0

Comment: I checked in 42 and it works. Try this in your version: http://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/XNogwd

Comment: I am searching for something interfering. What is weird is that on all other browsers (FF, Chrome, Safari), the table is centered.

Comment: Try giving the table a specific width and see does that help.

Comment: you'll have to show the code from your entire website, or as much as needed until you can get a demo which can replicate the problem.

Comment: you can see my issue on the following page : http://beulu.com/test_issue/ . As you can notice, the code box has text-aligned on left but the div is not centered horizontally. I have used this CSS rule : div.center-left table{
text-align: left;
margin: 0 auto;
}